# Golang: XML attributes from another struct

Tags: xml, go

How can I add an XML element attribute from another struct?

For example: http://play.golang.org/p/E3K1KYnRH8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Embed](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) the type with common attrs into your other types.

```
type AuthData struct {
    BuyerId  string `xml:"BuyerId,attr"`
    UserId   string `xml:"UserId,attr"`
    Language string `xml:"Language,attr"`
}

type MyRequest struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"MyRequest"`
    AuthData // Embedding.
    Action   struct{} `xml:"Action"`
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/u23HuwYgq2.